# MicrosoftAjax.js is not loaded successfully in word web add in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I am building a word web add-in with VS2015 and pretty much randomly (I don't change anything, then get this new error) office.js will crash with the error

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: MicrosoftAjax.js is not loaded successfully.
```

It is super frustrating because I cannot always repeat the error and the javascript engine afterwards completely crashes causing me to restart visual studio and reload the project (NOT fun when doing a live demo)

EDIT: attached html calling for officejs

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">

    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- To enable offline debugging using a local reference to Office.js, use:                        -->
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
    <!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->

    <link href="../App.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML from a page where this is happening? It may have something to do with how you are referencing the library.

Comment: I put it in the post - but like i said it is random when it happens - I got the code from the microsoft github -> https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-AddPopulateBindings

Comment: I switched to a local version of officejs vs the hosted file - I will see if the problem arises.

Comment: A couple other questions:
1) Are you including MicrosoftAjax.js manually in your app?  2) If you look at the network traffic using Fiddler, do you see MicrosoftAjax.js getting requested, and do you ever see an error?  3) And finally, what client version (Office 2013, 2016, etc) and version number are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am a little late on the answer, but I ran into the same issue.  This microsoft dev article addresses and provides the solution to this issue.

https://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-Store-add-in-validation-changes-using-MicrosoftAjax-js

Basically the new office.js script in the html, that used to load microsoft ajax does not any longer since 2016.  i.e.

```js
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Some functions like Excel.run were checking to make sure microsoft ajax was loaded and not working for me in an Excel add-in.  The solution is to just load ajax yourself, or if not using ajax reference the microsoft dev announcement above and load a different office.js package the announcement provides.